# Does digit separator has bug in C#?

Tags: c#, digit-separator

I am using following code:

```
do
{
    response = client.GetAsync(jobStatusURI).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        coverageResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(coverageResult))
        {
            int sleepTime = 3000; // Millisecond initialized
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
            LogAll.LogInfo($"Waiting for job result, sleeping for  : {sleepTime}", log);
        }
        else
            return coverageResult;
    }
    else
    {
        LogAll.LogError($"Failed to get result", log);
        break;
    }
    
} while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(coverageResult));
```

If you see I've set up sleep time as 3000 millisecond but actually its sleeping for 30 seconds i.e 30,000. Here is the log

> INFO 2019-02-28 14:55:12 – Waiting for job result, sleeping for : 3000
>
> INFO 2019-02-28 14:55:42 – Waiting for job result, sleeping for : 3000
>
> INFO 2019-02-28 14:56:12 – Waiting for job result, sleeping for : 3000
>
> INFO 2019-02-28 14:56:42 – Waiting for job result, sleeping for : 3000
>
> INFO 2019-02-28 14:57:12 – Waiting for job result, sleeping for : 3000
>
> INFO 2019-02-28 14:57:42 – Waiting for job result, sleeping for : 3000
>
> INFO 2019-02-28 14:58:12 – Waiting for job result, sleeping for : 3000
>
> INFO 2019-02-28 14:58:42 – Waiting for job result, sleeping for : 3000
>
> INFO 2019-02-28 14:59:12 – Waiting for job result, sleeping for : 3000
>
> INFO 2019-02-28 14:59:42 – Waiting for job result, sleeping for : 3000

Comment: Please explain the problem a little more elaborately, along with your desired behavior.

Comment: It is correctly sleeping for 3000ms, but it is doing it 10 times = 30000ms.

Comment: @i486 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#numeric-literal-syntax-improvements

Comment: Don't combine `Thread.Sleep` with `async` code, use (and await) `Task.Delay`

Comment: And use real async code, so not `.Result` but `await` that Task

Comment: I can not reproduce that. Your code compiles fine for me: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANALiAlgGxgExAagD4AEAMABLgIwDcAsAFC4DMxATIQMKEDe1hXx9uUhAWQAUASnadukyYgB2cQgGdkAU2UAHACqIAtssIBeQrQD6+M5SpSrxEgDoNACwBOygIZpZAc3vO3aWwDKKupCSqqaOsoiFtZSpACcQgAkAEQA6q6IcF6EAGYA9k6EAFb5wIQuCgCuyHAwisFqOQVFhCDsYepaugC+KdESXD3UPUA

Comment: Add another log message just before the Sleep to check the real sleep time. And note that client.GetAsync also takes time and is in the same loop

Comment: _Does digit separator has bug in C#?_ I would bet that the answer to this question is a big NO: before doubting about c# (or every mature and widespread language/framework) on such a basic feature, start thinking is your code having something wrong.

Comment: @SimplyGed Its a coincidence that in sample there are 10 log. If you look at difference between two log time its 30 seconds and not 3 second

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Is there a known limitation of using Thread.Sleep with async ? I would try Task.Delay and see. Also using await instead of result would require changing many function signature plus I dont need async call here so .Result is good for me

Comment: Thread.Sleep blocks the thread, Task.Delay frees it for other work